# Match word in a cell with a column of words

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I need to match a word to a list of words and then insert the category name in the cell next to it.

Eg.  I will in Column A type a list of words like Apple, Red Apple, Coke, Carrot
The formula must then find the word (or part of the word) in a List Column D and the place the Category in cell B next to the word.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have two slightly different options - choose which fits your needs most:

- generate category via `FILTER()`
- generate category via `REGEXMATCH()`

**SPREADSHEET: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Xc9jZ-9SGXTARf-4rxCZpIu50TmSMxQAeqixGVGAPY/edit#gid=791884555)**

**GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJOxV.gif** (open in new window)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this also does what you need but it has its own limitations...

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,D2:E,2,0)),
 ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A," ",1,1),,2),D2:E,2,0))),)
```

[image: x]

Comment: Thank you..Working 100% but only 1 question:
If the Words are "Sweet Red Apple" then I would like the formula to see the word "Apple" and then compare to List so it would then place "Fruit" in Type box.
Meaning the formula should see a part of the word and not the complete words

Comment: @JacoNel hence those "limitations" I mentioned... provided formula works only if there are max 2 words. to add 3 word support you will need to add 2nd row again to index out 3rd virtual column or implement some IF() nesting

Comment: @JacoNel https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers